# How to send a SMS with Twilio behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, sms, twilio

I am trying to send SMS with the Twilio API and I receive the following error: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I think this happens because the application is run behind a proxy.

How to make the Twilio API call with the proxy configured?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a way to do it using the Twilio API.

Here is my solution:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        ["From"] = _twilioFromPhone,
        ["To"] = phoneNumber,
        ["Body"] = body
    };

    var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(_accountSid + ":" + _authToken));
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

    client.Proxy = new WebProxy("[proxy address, not http in front]", proxy port number);

    var url = string.Format("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{0}/Messages", _accountSid);
    var response = client.UploadValues(url, values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```